# Where "with" is coupled with ? "make" or "session"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And then, trust the Japanese to *make* an opera out of what could have been *a humdrum reading session* **with** a reader, a reading lamp, and a group of people waiting for the promise to be redeemed.
> https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/redeem

Is this...? "Japanese to make an opera with a reader, a reading lamp, and a group of people waiting for the promise to be redeemed.(something like "I made the house with bricks") - here "with bricks" is an adverb phrase which modifies make.

or

"I made dinner out of materials with a long shelf life" - here "with a long shelf life" is an adjective phrase which modifies materials.

In other words, my question is : no. 1 or no. 2?

1. make something with A
2. something with A

Comment: Please include a source.

Comment: I don't see this passage under the link you have provided. However, the description  _with a reader, a reading lamp and a group of people_ clearly describes the _humdrum reading session_.

Comment: This sentence is in "more example sentences" in the "Fulfill or carry out (a pledge or promise)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example sentences are linked to the specific meanings. In this case it is "Fulfill or carry out (a pledge or promise)"

In this case the type of promise isn't clear because the context is missing in this short quote. It seems reasonable to understand "the promise" to be "the promise to tell a story" which could be redeemed by a simple reading, but which has been made into an "opera" (perhaps not literally), in a way that the writer thinks is typical of the Japanese.